# How to uninstall or remove TLP?

Tags: uninstall, power-management, battery, tlp

I searched but couldn't find how to uninstall TLP. I installed it but performance is weird. So I uninstalled it through Synaptic but I still have the icon of it running.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned here in answer #6 https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/249516

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove tlp
```

That will uninstall the TLP package and remove all configurartions

Answer (score 2):

Try opening a terminal and issuing the following commands:

`sudo apt-get remove tlp`

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:linrunner/tlp`

Comment: AU cares for [high quality answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) (and questions). While your answer may provide a viable solution, it lacks an explanation. Can you please [edit] your answer to elaborate on what these commands are supposed to do? You can also [format code and shell commands nicely](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).