# How to remove settings of TLP?

Tags: power-management, battery, tlp

I haven't yet figured out how to get TLP working nicely on my Ubuntu Thinkpad, as I had to scrap the broken battery the other day and replace it with a new one.

I've got my new battery in place now, but don't want TLP anymore. So I placed `TLP_ENABLE=0` via `sudo vim /etc/tlp.conf` (as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239176/how-to-disable-tlp)). I rebooted but the thresholds are still in place, meaning my battery is at 80% and not charging. So now I've [deleted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459260/how-to-uninstall-or-remove-tlp) TLP completly from my laptop, hoping that it would remove the threshold once and for all. But that isn't the case either.

So how do I remove the TLP settings completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FAQ is your friend -> https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html#faq-how-to-disable-thresholds

TL;DR: the thresholds are stored in hardware. Removing TLP does not disable them.

Instead temporarily reinstall TLP, then use the command

```
sudo tlp fullcharge
```

and uninstall again.